# ClassCastException causing app to stop

Tags: java, android

i'm having difficult to solve this, i already search through some similar problems, but i don't have experience this kind one, 
from my logcat i found this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.dot.analyticsdemo.DemoApp
                                                                                   at com.example.dot.analyticsdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
```

and this is my MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DemoApp application = (DemoApp) getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

        // starts a new session and notification to google analytics
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
                .setNewSession()
                .build());
    }
```

which line 23 is: `DemoApp application = (DemoApp) getApplication();`

this is the DemoApp:

```
package com.example.dot.analyticsdemo;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class DemoApp extends Application {

    private Tracker mTracker;

    /**
     * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
     * @return tracker
     */
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {

        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

            // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
            mTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
            mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
        }

        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

what is my mistake ?

Comment: what is `DemoApp` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FQ7rqapW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare application name in your manifest file ?

```
 <application
    android:name="[.path].DemoApp"
    .....
```